# Get complete UTC offset format

Tags: go, time, timezone, timezone-offset

I need to get the UTC offset for a location. I am getting trouble with the inconsistency of the results from different values. All I need to get are values in the format `+HHMM` (e.g., `+0100` for "Europe/Rome").

```
func main() {
    loc, _:= time.LoadLocation("Asia/Kathmandu")
    offset, others:= time.Now().In(loc).Zone()
    fmt.Println(offset, others)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/aVxflQ3Z9eU)

What I get:

- "Asia/Kathmandu": `+0545` (suitable)
- "Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh": `+07` (should be `+0700`)
- "America/Phoenix": `MST` (should be `-0700`)
- "Europe/Rome": `CET` (should be `+0100`)

[Reference Timezone country names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Answer (score 6):

The `Zone()` method you're using is working [exactly as advertized](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Zone).

> Zone computes the time zone in effect at time t, returning the abbreviated name of the zone (such as "CET") and its offset in seconds east of UTC.

A better approach for you would be to use the [`Format`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) method. Something like:

```
zone := time.Now().In(loc).Format("-0700")
```

Of course, be aware: Even this won't be 100% consistent, due to daylight savings time.